# Extra-Lorentzian Kac-Moody algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

My question is about Kac-Moody (KM) algebras  of finite rank   with symmetrized Cartan matrices $B = C A$ ($A$ is Cartan matrix) of signatures  $(-,-,+,...,+)$,   $(-,-,-,+,...,+)$, etc. i.e. with $2$, $3$  and so on time-like directions.   It will be of interest to find in literature the study of such  algebras, or, at least,  examples of Cartan matrices $A$, especially of rank $3$ and signature   $(-,-,+)$ and   of rank $4$  and signature  $(-,-,+,+)$.   What is known about  classification of such    ``extra-Lorentzian'' KM  algebras?